# List comprehension with nested lists (sublists)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

The below list comprehension works the way I want it to. My question is, is there a way to write the code without having to include all the specific element indices? The goal is to consolidate members of the sublists with their respective outer member, as per the included output.

```
myList = [['pKey_a', ['va1', 'va2', 'va3', 'va4']], ['pKey_b', ['vb1', 'vb2', 'vb3', 'vb4']], ['pKey_c', ['vc1', 'vc2', 'vc3', 'vc4']], ['pKey_d', ['vd1', 'vd2', 'vd3', 'vd4']], ['pKey_e', ['ve1', 've2', 've3', 've4']]]

myListComp = [[d[0], d[1][0], d[1][1], d[1][2], d[1][3]] for d in myList]

print myListComp
'''
[
['pKey_a', 'va1', 'va2', 'va3', 'va4'],
['pKey_b', 'vb1', 'vb2', 'vb3', 'vb4'],
['pKey_c', 'vc1', 'vc2', 'vc3', 'vc4'],
['pKey_d', 'vd1', 'vd2', 'vd3', 'vd4'],
['pKey_e', 've1', 've2', 've3', 've4']
]
'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list concatenation:

```
myListComp = [d[:1] + d[1] for d in myList]
```

Demo:

```
>>> myList = [['pKey_a', ['va1', 'va2', 'va3', 'va4']], ['pKey_b', ['vb1', 'vb2', 'vb3', 'vb4']], ['pKey_c', ['vc1', 'vc2', 'vc3', 'vc4']], ['pKey_d', ['vd1', 'vd2', 'vd3', 'vd4']], ['pKey_e', ['ve1', 've2', 've3', 've4']]]
>>> [d[:1] + d[1] for d in myList]
[['pKey_a', 'va1', 'va2', 'va3', 'va4'], ['pKey_b', 'vb1', 'vb2', 'vb3', 'vb4'], ['pKey_c', 'vc1', 'vc2', 'vc3', 'vc4'], ['pKey_d', 'vd1', 'vd2', 'vd3', 'vd4'], ['pKey_e', 've1', 've2', 've3', 've4']]
```